# Trying to install vmware with multiple operating systems

Tags: windows-xp, mac, partition-magic

I am trying to install Vmware with multiple operating systems on the PC.

Hardware: Intel i3 CPU, 4GB DDR3 and 500GB hard disk. Disk is partitioned as 100GB partition for Windows XP and rest is unpartitioned. I want to install Windows 2000, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Mac OS X and CentOS Linux.

Someone told me that I have to use Powerquest Partition Magic to set up partitions first.

What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Comment: VMware Workstation/Player or ESXi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you don't need VMWare if you don't want to run other operating systems as virtual machines.

Second, running Mac OS X on any other hardware than in Apple's computer is problematic (from hardware and from EULA point of view).

You don't have to use Partition Magic for disk partitioning.

### Virtual machines

If you want to run all those operating systems as virtual machines, you can just create one large partition, install VMWare to Windows XP, and then install other operating systems from VMWare, and create virtual disks, without need for disk partitions.

You can also run OS as a virtual machine from physical partition with VMWare.

### Dedicated operating systems

If you don't want to run virtual machine(s), you have to partition your disk and install capable bootloader.

Configuring Windows XP, Vista, 2000, 7 and Linux to same bootloader can be a little bit tricky operation, but I would start by installing Windows 2000, then Vista, then 7 and finally Linux. While installing Linux, you can choose to install `grub` (Linux bootloader), which can be used to boot to Windowses too.